# Notification after an address book contact gets updated/modified in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there is any notification passed after an update or change in a contacts Address Book information in iOS?

Comment: i'm using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29208841/2050181

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) to listen to updates in the Address Book.

---

You may also listen to the `@"ABCDataBaseChangedExternallyNotification"` notification, or even deeper, the `"__ABDataBaseChangedByOtherProcessNotification"` Darwin notification, but these are all *undocumented*. Don't rely on them. `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` is perfectly fine.