# How to get notified in contact changed event in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I wants to get notified when there is insert/update event to contacts of iPhone.

Is it possible to get notification to my app regarding specific contact changed event happened ?

Just a newbie... for IOS Swift.

I am not expecting full source code. Just wants to know whether its possible or not and also hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: KVO, and NSNotification both are solution for you. See these http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/ and http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS it could be done using -

Register the external change call back notifier-

```
ABAddressBookRef ntificationaddressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ntificationaddressbook, MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback, self);
```

Implement the call back -

```
void MyAddressBookExternalChangeCallback (ABAddressBookRef ntificationaddressbook,CFDictionaryRef info,void *context)
{
    // called when there is any change in AddressBook
}
```

For more details you can refer this link-

[Detect what was changed from ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440115/detect-what-was-changed-from-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback)

Comment: Very well answer @SanjayMohnani !!! I am trying to convert this to swift 2.0 but not able to do it properly. Could you please post the same from swift 2.0

Answer (score 32):

From iOS 9 you can register your class to observe *CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification*

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(addressBookDidChange),
    name: NSNotification.Name.CNContactStoreDidChange,
    object: nil)
```

And then:

```
@objc func addressBookDidChange(notification: NSNotification){     
    //Handle event here...
}
```

as reported in [Contacts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

> After a save is successfully executed, the contact store posts a
>   CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification notification to the default
>   notification center. If you cache any Contacts framework objects you
>   need to refetch those objects, either by their identifiers, or with
>   the predicates that were used to originally fetch them, and then
>   release the cached objects. Note that cached objects are stale, but
>   not invalid.

**EDIT:**

Note that Address Book and Address Book UI frameworks are now deprecated.

Comment: I got notification even when nothing in Contacts is changed. If I just open the system contacts and switch to my app, I got notification, and not just one, but two or three

Comment: Will it notify? If we kill the app and change something in addressbook.the open the app again

Comment: it's not notifying while the app is killed and contacts are changed and then open the app.

Comment: anyone found the solution even when the app is killed and contact is changes as Whatsapp doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `KeyValue Observers` `observevalueforkeypath` to get notified for status change of selected elements