# How to return to app after saving contacts - React Native - react-native-contacts

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-contacts` inside my react native app to save a contact.

Before saving I request WRITE permission from android.
It works, I open the contact form through my app and save it using the contact form. The contact is saving properly. But, after I have saved the contact, it goes to the home screen, not to my app.

I want to return to my app after the contact is saved.

here is my code,

```
saveContact = user => {
  var newPerson = {
    emailAddresses: [
      {
        label: "work",
        email: user.email
      }
    ],
    phoneNumbers: [
      {
        label: "mobile",
        number: user.mobileNumber
      }
    ],
    displayName: user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
  };

  PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS, {
    title: "Contacts",
    message: "This app would like to write contacts.",
    buttonPositive: "Please accept bare mortal"
  }).then(() => {
    Contacts.openContactForm(newPerson, (err, contact) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // contact has been saved
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: If the app is crashing, post the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are talking about Callback when **openContactForm** when creation screen is closed

This issue is still **OPEN** on their [github issue page](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts/issues/276) and this feature is still not given by package owner.

For instance, you can see for iOS this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208605/how-to-get-notified-in-contact-changed-event-in-ios/29208841#29208841)

I think for now you need to add event listeners for both android and ios separately.

For more information about handling event listeners [here](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts/issues/314)

Comment: glad it helps :)